# Debian Wheezy crackling sound on shutdown

Tags: linux, audio, debian, shutdown

Crackling sound is coming out of my internal and external speakers as well when I shutdown or reboot my HP 8540w notebook.

```
lspci | grep Aud
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: IDT 92HD75B3X5
Codec: LSI ID 1040
```

**I was able to get rid of this problem** adding:

```
options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, **but my computer stopped to recognize Headphones when plugged**.

I tried to mute alsa before restart, but crackling sound still remains.

I use following `~/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.pulse {
    type pulse
}

ctl.pulse {
    type pulse
}

pcm.!default {
    type pulse
}

ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}
```

Maybe this happens because of wrong `options snd-hda-intel` `model`, `power_save` or whatever setting. I have already tried several configurations, but always without success.

Comment: Try adding in an actual question to this post